# How to use JMS Properties on IBM MQ JMS Interface?

Tags: properties, jms, ibm-mq

I'm using MQ JMS interface with MQ 6.0.2.

It seems that only pre defined properties are suported and not arbitrary ones.
for instance, I can properly `getJMSCorrelationID()`, `getJMSPriority()` etc. However, when i set an arbitrary property on the sender:

```
message.setStringProperty("my arbitrary name", "value");
```

I can't get the property from the message on the receiver:

```
message.getStringProperty("my arbitrary name");
```

I simply get `null`.

Is there a way to do that as in any JMS implementation, or is that an MQ JMS limitation?

Comment: By the way, your last question was about WebSphere MQ but the title here is 'MS JMS'.  Are you using MSMQ or WMQ?  If it's WebSphere MQ, make sure to use the tag websphere-mq instead of or in addition to the more generic tag mq so it will be found faster.  All of the mq tags are fairly low-volume here so the more specific you are, the more likely your question is to be found.  I was about to retag and it occurred to me this might actually be an MSMQ question.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the complete client install, you can go to `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\jms\samples\interactive\` or somewhere in `/opt/mqm/samp` and look for `SampleConsumerJava.java` and `SampleProducerJava.java`.

From the sample Producer program:

```
  // Set custom properties
  msg.setStringProperty("MyStringProperty", "My Year Of Birth");
  msg.setIntProperty("MyIntProperty", 2007);
```

And from the sample Consumer:

```
  // Get values for custom properties, if available
  String property1 = msg.getStringProperty("MyStringProperty");

  // Get value for an int property, store the result in long to validate
  // the get operation.
  long property2 = ((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1;
  property2 = msg.getIntProperty("MyIntProperty");

  if ((property1 != null) && (property2 < Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    System.out.println("[Message has my custom properties]");
```

Property names follow the rules for Java variable names and cant have spaces in them.

Comment: +1 for the code samples and mentioning the full client install.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [JMS 1.1 specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jms/index.html):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length
>   character sequence that must begin
>   with a Java identifier start
>   character; all following characters
>   must be Java identifier part
>   characters. An identifier start
>   character is any character for which
>   the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierStart
>   returns true. This includes ‘_’ and
>   ‘$’. An identifier part character is
>   any character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierPart returns
>   true.

Following the clues here takes us to the Javadoc for the [Character.isJavaIdentifierPart](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart%28int%29) method which lists the valid characters for an identifier:

> A character may be part of a Java
>   identifier if any of the following are
>   true:
>
> ```
> * it is a letter
> * it is a currency symbol (such as '$')
> * it is a connecting punctuation character (such as '_')
> * it is a digit
> * it is a numeric letter (such as a Roman numeral character)
> * it is a combining mark
> * it is a non-spacing mark
> * isIdentifierIgnorable(codePoint) returns true for the character
> ```

Note that white space is specifically excluded from the set of valid identifier characters.  The [set of valid first characters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart%28char%29) is a little more restrictive and includes the following characters:

> ```
> * isLetter(ch) returns true
> * getType(ch) returns LETTER_NUMBER
> * ch is a currency symbol (such as "$")
> * ch is a connecting punctuation character (such as "_").
> ```

Use a valid identifier and try again.  For example:

`message.setStringProperty("my.arbitrary.name", "value");`
`message.getStringProperty("my.arbitrary.name");`

Or possibly...

`message.setStringProperty("myArbitraryName", "value");`
`message.getStringProperty("myArbitraryName");`

By the way, switch to V7 at your earliest opportunity.  Not only is the support for properties much better in general, but the ability to directly read/write MQMD headers is vastly improved [as shown in the IBM example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm41030_.htm).

Comment: I'm sorrey, this is not clear to me :-( are you suggesting I should change the code to something else then message.setStringProperty("my arbitrary name", "value");
? could you give an example?

Comment: Basically, identifiers can't have embedded white space.  Substitute a valid char or run them together like a Java variable name: `myArbitraryProperty`.