# Syntax of JMS Header property

Tags: properties, header, jms, illegalargumentexception

I am getting the an error while executing the code below

```
jmsMsg.setStringProperty("MessageHeader.ServiceName","MyService");
```

The error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property name 'MessageHeader.ServiceName' is not a valid java identifier.
```

But as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847248/how-to-use-jms-properties-on-ibm-mq-jms-interface)! my property name is a valid one.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it likes the . (dot) character in the name.  Can you can that to something like underscore and see if that works?  I get a false when running Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('c').