# MQ error when setting message header

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to set a custom header on an MQ message, but when I do I get an MQException (2142) with 2195 also written to StdErr.  In the code below, there is a call for mqMessage.setStringProperty ... if I remove that line, this code works.  I am trying to follow what I see here: [How to use JMS Properties on IBM MQ JMS Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847248/how-to-use-jms-properties-on-ibm-mq-jms-interface)

```
private MQQueueManager qm;
private MQQueue queue;

private void initialize() throws Exception {
    MQEnvironment.hostname = "myhost";
    MQEnvironment.port = 1234;
    MQEnvironment.channel = "channelname"; 

    qm = new MQQueueManager( "QMgrName" );
    queue = qm.accessQueue( 
                "QueueName", 
                CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING );
}

private void sendMessage() throws Exception {
    MQMessage mqMessage = new MQMessage();
    mqMessage.format = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING;
    mqMessage.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;

    MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
    pmo.options = CMQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT;

    // The problem line
    mqMessage.setStringProperty("header.name", "value");

    mqMessage.writeString( "This is a test");
    queue.put(mqMessage, pmo);
}
```

Comment: OK - so the problem is that I wasn't including the pcf jar (not sure what that one actually does.)  Found the answer from this [link](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=61573&sid=721fe70577840f9044504a1d11d5a2d3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable name is invalid:

> "header.name"

Change it to headerName and it will work.

Comment: Strange. Can you post your full stacktrace?

Comment: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2142'.
     at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.writePropertiesRfh2(MQMessage.java:3310)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.performProcessingBeforePut(MQMessage.java:3156)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.put(MQDestination.java:1108)
     at com.wellsfargo.isg.logmanager.mq.HeaderTest.sendMessage(HeaderTest.java:48)
     at com.wellsfargo.isg.logmanager.mq.HeaderTest.simpleTest(HeaderTest.java:22)

Comment: Do you have this jar on your classpath:
com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar ?

Comment: As mentioned above, that is exactly what was missing.  Thanks for your help!  :)